# Convert Mel-spectrogram PNG to Voice using Librosa is it possible?

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network, librosa, spectrogram

can i convert a mel-spectrogram png to voice 'wav' with python(librosa,scipy..)

cause i have gan project that generate mel-spectrogram images and i wan't to converte them to voice again

my processe is :

1-converte wav to mel-spectrogram and save the result as png

2-feed the png result to the generator

3-result of generator is mel-spectrogram save the result as png

4-THE PROBLEM => **"CONVERTE PNG RESULT OF GENERATOR TO WAV AGAIN"**

any solution ,or alternative to produce this cycle will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you save melspectrogram .tiff the values do not change and u can see the spectrogram in grayscale

```
#from wav to tiff
y, sr = librosa.load(songname)
whale_song, _ = librosa.effects.trim(y)
n_fft=2048
hop_length=512
n_mels=128
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(whale_song, sr=sr, n_fft=n_fft, 
                                hop_length=hop_length, n_mels=n_mels)
from PIL import Image
im =Image.fromarray(S).convert('F') 
im.show()
im.save("/content/gdrive/My Drive/sp.tiff")

#from tiff to wav 
m=Image.open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/sp.tiff") 
import numpy as np
img=np.array(im)
wav=librosa.feature.inverse.mel_to_audio(img)
print(img)
import soundfile
soundfile.write("4.wav",wav,samplerate=sr)`
```

Comment: thnx for this idea a will try it and tell you if its work